# cannot connect to wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, wifi-driver, networkmanager

I have a problem with conecting to my wifi. I see my wifi, but when i am trying to connect to it- i write the password and the password-window pop up again like the password is wrong (but it is good, on another laptop's ubuntu and on this laptop's windows everything is running just ok)

info:

**cat /proc/version**

```
Linux version 3.16.4-200.fc20.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel02.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Oct 6 12:57:00 UTC 2014
```

**lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net**

```
7:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8195]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

I have tried to install drivers from https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/ but itwont compile.

I've set the MAC of the router to be the same as my laptop's MAC.

can some1 help? Lately I have lots of problems with this system and not a lot of time to learn step by step, sadly.

Comment: pls add the output of `tail -n20 /var/log/wpa_supplicant` just after trying to connect to the wifi network.

Comment: I'm trying but there is  no wpa_supplicant. I've tried few methods of enabling it (eg from https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/Debugging). I'll try to make this work and post results but for now I cannot.